# Why is my CSV writing my entire page in addition to the array(s) I'm trying to write to the file?

Tags: php

I have a very specific set of arrays I'm trying to write to a CSV file, which I then want to automatically download. The code happens inside a while loop, which does seem to output the correct values into the CSV. The problem I'm having is that the CSV also seems to be adding all of the html from the page as well. Seems like a simple mistake but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my code on the page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    exit();
    include 'db.php';
    include 'header.php';
?>
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['download'])) {
    $name = $_POST['submit'];

    $findskusets = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM skusearch WHERE tier1a = '$name' OR tier1b = '$name' OR tier1c = '$name' OR tier1d = '$name' OR tier1e = '$name'");

    while ($skusetrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findskusets)) {// for each sku row that contains this account as a recipient

        $skusearchquery = $skusetrow['skusearchquery'];
        $findskus = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sku LIKE '%$skusearchquery%'");

        while ($skurow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findskus)) { // for each sku contained in the sku set
            $openfile = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            $sku = $skurow['sku'];
            $paid = $skurow['paid'];
            $info = array($sku, $paid);
            fputcsv($openfile, $info);
            fclose($openfile);
        }

    }


}

?>


</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the output I'm getting in a text file. The chunk with all of the numbers and letters should be there - the HTML stuff is what I don't want. This should be a plain and simple CSV.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jakub's Number Cruncher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="import-filters.php">Import Filters</a>
        <a href="import-skus.php">Import SKUs</a>
        <a href="accounts.php">View Accounts</a>
    </nav>
</head><body>

JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-VG_3,7.21
JGK-2017-FEB-16-SAS-B-VG_7,4.15
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-VG_1,6.82
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-LN_8,1.51
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-N_10,9.76
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-TOY-N_2,15.39
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-LN_2,4.66
JGK-2017-FEB-16-GW-B-LN_9,11.07
JGK-2017-FEB-16-SAS-B-VG_3,7.21
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_33,4.42
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_18,4.84
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-VG_13,3.14
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_27,2.96
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_25,11.46
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_15,35.4
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_35,3.42
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-LN_14,5.58
JKG-2017-FEB-13-GW-B-VG_7,1.6


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're also outputting the surrounding HTML.  For example, here:

```
include 'header.php';
```

and here:

```
<body>
```

and here:

```
</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

(twice for some reason)

If you don't want to output the HTML, then remove the HTML from your PHP file.  Only output the data you want.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it. So you can't just make your file in the middle of a page without making a separate page that doesn't contain anything else around it?

Comment: @Tyler: Well, you can structure your output however you want.  The point is that whatever you tell the code to output, that's what it's going to output.  So when you include HTML, it'll show HTML.

Comment: I guess my confusion is, I never told it to output HTML. I very specifically wrote to the csv a specific array, and yet it's adding all of this stuff that is not contained in an fputcsv. So I guess that's what is throwing me off.

Comment: @Tyler: `"I never told it to output HTML"` - Look at your code.  There's HTML in it.  And I strongly suspect `header.php` contains the rest of the HTML that's being output which isn't in the file shown in the question.  The HTML you're outputting is *right there* in the code you're showing us.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I do understand that the file is outputting all of my HTML code, but I still don't understand why. I specifically opened the file inside of a loop with NO HTML, using  `$openfile = fopen('php://output', 'w');`, then I specifically wrote one line to the file: `fputcsv($openfile, $info);` and then I closed the file with `fclose($openfile);`. The whole point of this question is why does the PHP _not seem to care_ that I am opening the file, only writing 1 line, and then closing it. Instead it outputs EVERYTHING on the page even though I didn't "tell it"

Comment: @Tyler: The "file" you are opening isn't an actual file, it's PHP's output buffer to the browser.  (Notice the name of the "file": `php://output`)  So PHP is writing the CSV data to the output that it sends to the browser.  It's also writing everything else you send to the output that it sends to the browser.  Including the HTML that's in your code, like any other PHP file.  For example, see in your code where you have `<body>`?  Any HTML (or any content really) that's outside of `<?php ?>` tags will be sent to the output.  That's how PHP works.